# how to update BufferGeometry that has children without using 'scene.add' more than once

Tags: three.js, buffer-geometry

my question is very specific. I have created a mesh (Mesh1) with bufferGeometry which is updated by some parameters, but another mesh (Mesh2) has been added to it by "add" method (Mesh1.add(Mesh2)). For the initialisation, I do scene.add(Mesh1), and obviously both meshes are shown on the screen. but once I update the Mesh1, the Mesh2 disappear, unless I do scene.add(Mesh1) again which is unnecessary, because it adds the Mesh1 to the screen one more time.
I was wondering if anyone can help me with this.
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was that I updated the mesh each time I made a change to the geometry, but it was not necesssary.